# ¿Como crear mi propio servidor de Git?

Tags: git, git-push

Estoy tratando de trabajar con `Git` y me surgen algunos problemas. El esquema es el siguiente:

Tengo dos PCs en mi casa, uno lo quiero como servidor, para alojar mis proyectos y el otro lo quiero para clonar dichos proyectos. El problema surge a la hora de clonar. Los dos PCs tienen Linux y creados los usuarios `git` y sus emails.

El PC que actúa como servidor tiene un repositorio creado en la siguiente ruta:

`var/www/html/carpeta_del_proyecto/repositorio.git`

Y desde el PC cliente quiero clonarla. He leído que hay varios métodos de acceso como `git`, `ssh` y `http`.

He generado las claves `ssh` desde el cliente y el servidor, y la llave `ssh` pública de mi cliente ya la he agregado al archivo `/.ssh/authorized_keys`  de mi servidor.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal que no puedo clonarlo?

He intentado los siguientes comandos:

1. `git clone git@ip_local_servidor/usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git`
2. `git clone git@ip_pública_servidor/usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git`
3. `git clone ssh://usuario_servidor@ip_pública_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git`
4. `git clone http://ip_pública_servidor/usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git`
5. `git clone+ssh://usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git`

El último (el número 5) no estoy muy seguro, solo lo copié de internet y edité el usuario y la ruta, pero el encabezado `clone+ssh` no sé si se deja así o se refiere a algo más.

Les agradecería si me pueden ayudar y responder, estoy intentando esto hace semanas y no consigo lograrlo.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Pd: He probado con diferentes `IPs`, la local que es dada por mi router, y la pública cuando me conecto a internet. El ejemplo 1 y 2 son iguales, solo tienen diferentes `IPs`.

Comment: ¿Qué errores aparecen con cada comando?

Comment: Al principio me aparecía esto:
Please make sure you have the correct acces rights and the repository exists.

Luego cuando intente otras cosas que encontré por internet me pidió la contraseña pero me dice error (puse la contraseña de inicio de sesión del servidor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al final el problema que tenía era que los puertos estaban cerrados y por eso no podía acceder desde el PC de donde lo quería clonar.

Abrí un **puerto del servidor** con el siguiente comando:

```
$ sudo ufw allow <número de puerto>
```

Lo saqué desde esta página: [Configurar el *firewall UWF* en *Ubuntu*](https://computernewage.com/2014/08/10/como-configurar-el-firewall-ufw-en-ubuntu/)

Luego tuve que configurar mi enrutador para hacer un mapeo de puertos (abrí un puerto *rel router* y lo conecté con el puerto abierto del servidor), esto varía según el enrutador y la configuración del mismo (Se puede buscar o encontrar como *NAT* en dicha configuración).

Una vez hecho esto comprobé si los puertos estaban abiertos con la siguiente página: [*Scan online* de puertos](http://www.internautas.org/w-scanonline.php)

Y por último me creé una cuenta *No-IP*, instalé su cliente y lo configuré para asociar mi **IP pública** a un nombre que yo le quisiera poner a mi *DNS*.
De esta manera ya podía clonar mi repositorio con la siguiente línea:

```
git clone ssh://usuario_git@nombre_del_dns:puerto_abierto_del_router/ruta_del_repo
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la ruta que estás usando para acceder a tu repositorio no es la correcta. El comando que deberías usar sería este:

```
git clone user@ip_servidor:/var/www/html/carpeta_del_proyecto/repositorio.git
```

Además, podrías tener un problema de permisos, para asegurarte podrías usar el comando `scp` y verificar si ese usuario tiene permisos de lectura y escritura sobre esa capeta y si te está funcionando el acceso por `ssh`.
Si vas a tener un único usuario, ubicar el repositorio en la carpeta de usuario podría simplificarlo.

Échale un vistazo a [este](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Poniendo-Git-en-un-Servidor) enlace donde tienes documentado como crear un servidor de **Git**

También podrías montarte un servidor mas avanzado usando la edición Community de [GitLab](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/), pero eso ya depende de tus necesidades.

Comment: Creo que es por problemas de permisos, prove ese comando que me dio y nada. Estuve probando otras cosas como instalar ssh-server.
Como hago para obtener permisos? Me pide una contraseña y creí que era la de inicio de logueo en el servidor, pero cuando la ingreso me dice que no es.

Comment: @FabricioNahuel Por lo que dices tiene pinta de ser un problema de permisos o, mas bien, de inicio de sesión. Lo primero que haría es comprobar que puedes iniciar sesión por `ssh` desde el equipo cliente. Después comprobaría que puedo copiar los archivos con `scp` (también desde el equipo cliente). Otra de las cosas que haría sería mover el repositorio a otra carpeta por ejemplo a la `/opt` o a la del usuario

Comment: @FabricioNahuel Por cierto, cuando usaste el comando `git clone git@ip_local_servidor/usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git` el repositorio debería estar ubicado en `/home/usuario_servidor/ruta_del_repo/repositorio.git` y el usuario `git`debería tener permisos de acceso sobre los archivos de esta carpeta.

Comment: @FabricioNahuel para el tema de los permisos podrías ejecutar este comando `chmod -R ug+rw foldername`para conceder permisos de lectura/escritura al usuario y grupo. También tendrías que comprobar con un `ls -l`que los propietarios y los grupos son los correctos.